# SQL UPDATE нескольких таблиц с разными полями в один запрос

Tags: sqlite3, sql

Доброго времени суток!

Ситуация такая: есть главная таблица и ещё несколько. Все они связаны через ключ:

```
главная.id = следующая1.id = следующая2.id = ...
```

Надо произвести обновление набора полей данных, которые (поля) располагаются во всём наборе таблиц.

Например: есть главная таблица и +100500 таблиц, связанных с ней через ключ (ключ везде одинаковый) и надо обновить 2 поля. Одно поле есть ТОЛЬКО в главной таблице, а другое ТОЛЬКО в таблице самого нижнего уровня.

Вопрос: можно ли как-то исхитриться и за один запрос это всё провернуть либо единственный способ - посылать Update-ы каждой из таблиц, которую обновляем?
Можно ли собрать все эти таблицы JOIN-ом в одну и её обновить?

Что-то типа:

```
UPDATE Главная INNER JOIN следующая1 ON Главная.ID = Следующая1.ID
SET .....
```

Или вариант только один: обновлять каждую таблицу отдельно?

Заранее благодарен!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Нет, вы не можете обновлять несколько таблиц одновременно. В некоторых базах можно обновлять одну таблицу, основываясь на сложном запросе из нескольких (не делая вложенных запросов, я имею в виду).

Answer (score 0):

Проще всего поставить триггер, который сам будет обновлять все подчиненные таблицы при обновлении главной.